# Custom user model with python-social-auth on django

Tags: python, django, steam, python-social-auth

I am new to this so sorry if what I am asking sounds silly. I am using only steamopenid on python-social-auth for the login, that's the only option the customer will have. Now I want to create my own custom user model where I can keep the user data once they log in. I believe it should not be too complicated but I can't find anything that seems correct.

I have managed to get username but I want to also get everything that's under user social auths table and users table. The fields that are saved into python-social-auth generated table: [image: Database]

settings.py

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
    'main.pipeline.save_profile',
)
```

pipeline.py

```
from .models import CustomUser


def save_profile(backend, user, response, *args, **kwargs):
    CustomUser.objects.create(
        user = user,
    )
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.

class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

New models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser




# Create your models here.

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    steam_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    steam_id = models.CharField(max_length=17, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    extra_data = models.TextField(null=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, db_column='status')
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_column='isstaff')
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_column='issuperuser')

    USERNAME_FIELD = "name"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["username"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a model which has a reference to the default user model of django. But I think that you want is customize your own model user. The option that i prefer is code a new model that inherits from `AbstractBaseUser`, which just have a few fields and you be able to add your own needed fields (if you want to use the admin site make sure of append `is_staff`, `is_superuser` and to make better control override `is_active`).

The last step is change in `settings.py` to use this model as your user model. I

```
from app.models impor NameModelUser
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.NameModelUser'
```

For more of this, check the documentation: [Specifying a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)

Now to catch the data of steam, that I have done is create a function to use in my pipeline of PSA. Basically you only have to put the correct parameters and get the data of them.
Example:

```
def save_buyer(backend, response, details, user, *args, **kwargs) -> Dict[str, any]:
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    backend: Union[GoogleOpenIdConnect, FacebookOAuth2, TwitterOAuth]
        Instance of the provider used to the authentication.
    response: Dict[str, str]
        The response of the Oauth request in json format.
    details: Dict[str, str]
        The response with user details in provider.
    user: Usuario
        Instance of the user (already registered).
    kwargs: Dict[str, bool]
        Distinct data about the execution of the pipeline.
    """
    last_name = details['last_name'] if details['last_name'] != '' else None
    if backend.name == 'facebook':
        MyUserModel(
            email=user,
            name=details['first_name'],
            last_name=last_name
        ).save()
```

So the key are details, user and even the response (for other data).
See more in [Extending the Pipeline](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html#extending-the-pipeline).

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Your welcome. Sorry, I forgot mention that to be able use the `user` parameter, you should list your new function after the `'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user'` in `'SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE'` because these are executed in sequence order.

Other option is modify the '`'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user'`  to give the user with all the data that you desire in this stage. I prefer no modify PSA functions and create a new one as I wrote in the answer, but it is your decision.

Comment: Hey I am almost where I wanted to get. I have added CustomUser model as abstract user and using the pipeline to add all the data I want. But now I have a problem when trying to log in, it gives me this error: UserManager.create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'

I have added the new models.py code at the end of the post.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this is happening? @Jony_23

Comment: If you pass the 'username' at the moment of make `user.save()`, the error should not appear. Other solution impliying write more code, but it gives a better control of your users, it is write your own Manager of your user model to manage how create the user instances.
There's a lot of tutorial on the web, here it is one [Creating a Custom User Model in Django](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/).